# iOS - Parsing JSON Dictionary with NSJSONSerialization in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

i am using my REST Webservice to get the JSON Data i want, this works as intended and prints:

```
 [{
    "name": "Event1",
    "genre": "Party",
    "subtitle": "subtitle1",
    "startDate": "2015-10-10",
    "location": "Anywhere"
  },
  {
    "name": "Event2",
    "genre": "Party",
    "subtitle": "subtitle2",
    "startDate": "2015-10-10",
    "location": "Anywhere"
  }]
```

So this seems to be an Array with 2 Elements which are Dictionaries.

I then tried to parse the JSON with NSJSONSerialization.

```
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]

            if let name = json["name"] as? [String]{
                print(name)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

I do get this error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x1096c1ae0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1096c1d60).
```

which seems pretty clear to me, but i just don't know how to solve it.

My goal would be to create "Event" Objects from my own class.

Comment: `json` is a array of dictionary. With that `json["name"]` you're assuming it's a dictionary, which is not. So `json[0]['name"]`?

Comment: have you tried SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the deserialization will be an array:

```
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

do {
    let dataArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSArray

    for event in dataArray {
        print(event)
    }

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```